# Breit–Wheeler experimental evidence?

Tags: particle-physics, quantum-electrodynamics

has there been any experimental evidence of the [Breit–Wheeler process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breit%E2%80%93Wheeler_process)? Either in it's full or weak form, would you have some links to back this up?

Can we say that all matter is merely energy condensed to a slow vibration? How could we formalize this idea with the current language of physics or quantum  gravity?

Would this mean that bosons and fermions come from a single unified field?

Or perhaps that there is an equivalence between mass and energy

Comment: This appears as a runaway list question. The first on the list is handled in [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breit%E2%80%93Wheeler_process#Experimental_observations).

Answer (score 0):

We know that matter and antimatter annihilate into two photons. For instance, in positron emission tomography, it has been experimentally proved. So *it should be just as viable* that two photons can create matter antimatter.

*e$^-$+ e$^+$* →   ✓

→ *e$^-$+ e$^+$* ✓?

But, unfortunately, this has not been achieved in experiments because you need photons with such an high energy. The energy required is given by the following: $$  \sqrt{{s}}= \sqrt{ 2\left [ { {1-\cos}} (θ \right)]}.$$

Given that the *energy required is too high, it is therefore almost impossible to do*,

so there is *no experimental evidence*.

But it is allowed and holds true given Einstein's theory of special relativity: *E = mc$^2$*

[image]